# I'm getting a "No Form Handler error" when executing my tests - RobotFramework

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, robotframework, salesforce-lightning

Im using https://cumulusci.readthedocs.io/en/stable/Keywords.html and we are testing a Form (create account) using the "Input form data" keyword from this library. My colleague runs the exact same test on his windows laptop and it works fine... Myself (on a mac) I'm getting

```
the following error for this keyword:
There were errors with the following fields:
First Name: No form handler found for 'First Name' (tag: 'lightning-primitive-input-simple')
Last Name: No form handler found for 'Last Name' (tag: 'lightning-primitive-input-simple')
Legal Credit %: No form handler found for 'Legal Credit %' (tag: 'lightning-primitive-input-simple')
Gift Recognition Credit %: No form handler found for 'Gift Recognition Credit %' (tag: 'lightning-primitive-input-simple')
```

Have anyone of you experience this error with Selenium-robot?

THIS IS THE KEYWORD I'm using:

```
Fill in all required fields for the Quick Create form
    ${firstName}        Get fake data       first_name
    ${lastName}         Get fake data       last_name
    Input form data
    ...     First Name                  ${firstName}
    ...     Last Name                   ${lastName}
    ...     Contact Type                Alumna/Alumnus
    ...     Account Relationship        Head of Household
    ...     Legal Credit %              100
    ...     Gift Recognition Credit %   100
```

THAT "INPUT FORM DATA" is a custom keyword from that salesforce library I mention above. I'm not sure how to fix it.. as I said running on a local windows laptop (from my colleague) this works fine.

I Have tried adding waits but still not working.